# Get memory details of JVM through process ID

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

Lets say I have several JVMs  running for several processes like  JBoss , MyOwnjavaApplication, Apache etc.
How to find out how many JVM's are running currently on a machine? and How do I get JVM memory usage of particular process ID . Lets say Jboss server process Id is 1234. So I want to know JVM memory usage of a process with process Id 1234.

Answer (score 1):

Use VisualVM to monitor your java applications.

Go to your java installed bin path and execute jvisualvm.exe

In windows i will do like below.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin> jvisualvm.exe
```

Please refer this [VisualVM tutorial](http://visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html)

Comment: How do I do it in linux(Fedora)? Cant we acheive this programatically using some API method calls?

Comment: @Stunner It will work on linux too. You can remote profile using VisualVM or use Netbeans profiler https://profiler.netbeans.org/. Sorry i am not aware of any  API.

Comment: Yes..Its working in linux also. Is there any way to export the data ? The memory usage is showing as graph analysis. Can i export the results to a file ?

Comment: @Stunner yes you can take snapshot from VisualVM  and export the snapshot. Whenever you want to view the snapshot you can import the saved snapshot to the VisualVM.

Comment: It will be in image format .But I wont be getting it in text format if i want to analyze and process that data,